# Unexpected response code 401 for Microsoft Graph me/calendars API in Android with volley lib

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Getting **Unexpected response code Http 401** error while calling GET **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars** API from android using volley library.

I have already added all the required permissions like Calendars.Read, Calendars.Read.Shared, Calendars.ReadWrite, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared etc

## History :

I have set up android project for calling Microsoft Graph API from below link:
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android**

Using dependencies in gradle build file : implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.3.+'

I am able to login and logout from android application .

Also i am able to access  **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me** API and getting proper response from microsoft server.

But getting error in other Graph API. Please find below connection method for Calendar API call:

**volloy network call for Calendar API**

```
    /* Make sure we have a token to send to graph */
    if (authResult.getAccessToken() == null) {
        return;
    }

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars",
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            /* Successfully called graph, process data and send to UI */
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());
        }

    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.getAccessToken());
            return headers;
        }
    };

    Log.d(TAG, "Adding HTTP GET to Queue, Request: " + request.toString());
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(request);
```

Response from above API call :
Unexpected response code 401 for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars

Kindly help me to call Graph API through android app using volley class.

Comment: My Issue is resolved now. Above code is right , the problem is that i have register my application under "Owned applications" tab in Azure Active Directory admin center portal. I have to re-register it in "Applications from personal account" tab since i am using my personal live account for testing.